# asp.net MVC responding to jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following code in a razor .cshtml file.  Clicking a button should fire an ajax GET request which should pop up an alert with whatever data the server returned. (the JS below is within document.ready)

```
    $("#ajax-form").click(function () {

        alert("event fired");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/apartments/getData',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

And the view code:

```
<div class="row">
    <form id="ajax-form">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string getData()
    {
        return "Some dummy data here";
    }
```

The event is definitely firing but the request fails (the error function fires). I could not get this to work with $.post or $.get either. Also typing localhost:54637/apartments/getData opens a page with "Some dummy data here".

Any ideas? Is there some particular way an asp.net MVC route must be settup to respond to an AJAX request?

Comment: please pot your view as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use form **submit** event, when form is submitted ajax request will be sent:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$("#ajax-form").submit(function () {

        alert("event fired");

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getData","apartments")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

or you can use submit button **click** event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$('#ajax-form input[type="submit"]').click(function () {

        alert("event fired");

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getData","apartments")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Update:**

you can post form via ajax this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#ajax-form").submit(function (e) {
     var form = $(this);
            alert("event fired");

            $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form .attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );

       e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
       e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... tried both the submit and click events.  The event fired dialogue pops so the event is wired correctly! Just have no idea why the request fails...

Comment: Like I said the route is definitely working because putting:  http://localhost:54637/Apartments/Index  in the url window returns the data!

Comment: Yea it does reload afterward the alert("error") fires

Comment: if you want to send ajax call after form data processed on server post form via ajax, bec because when form postes page reloads and clinet script will not be executed completely

Comment: I just changed the `<form>` to just a `<button>` and it works... damn.  I understand what you mean now.  What is the correct way to submit data from a `<form>` via ajax then?  Would you mind updating your answer with a sample?

Comment: Couldn't get that to work either... but it's easier to just use a textbox/button anyway. Thanks for your help, I'll accept/upvote the answer

Comment: if you dont want want to process form data on server you can go with the button as your are saying

Comment: Cool, how does that differ from just sending the textarea content?

Comment: if you have lot of fields then form post is most preffered if you have just on field send it in Get Request will be fine enough

Comment: Awww I guess this is advantageous for routes that take a model type as a parameter for validation and such.  Thanks